Error encountered during the callback with Chainlink Functions
I need help with Chainlink Functions, I have a smart contract deployed and working, the problem is when I call the "RequestNFT" function, I enter a link with metadata, specifically image, name and description.
With this link a "Callback" error is shown but the "Computation" does work all of this in Chainlink Functions:
https://ipfs.io/ipfs/QmUFbUjAifv9GwJo7ufTB5sccnrNqELhDMafoEmZdPPng7
{
    "name": "NFT Art",
    "description": "This image shows the true nature of NFT.",
    "image": "https://ipfs.io/ipfs/QmQEVVLJUR1WLN15S49rzDJsSP7za9DxeqpUzWuG4aondg",
}


And with the following link it gives me another "Computation" error but the "Callback" does work:
https://ipfs.io/ipfs/QmcusKgN4XKSLcJjHD9WF7WAuww6mmcGUkUWKgQsXhW7vA/photo01.json
{
  "name": "Tiger 01",
  "description": "Tiger",
  "image": "https://ipfs.io/ipfs/QmfMQdqPvpSzVq4GjxgHpk4qS69kWeVCxcwsiTGNDvkRm1/Tiger-001.JPG",
  "attributes": [
      {
        "trait-type": "Type",
        "value": "Bengal"        
      },
      {
        "trait-type": "Location",
        "value": "Tampa"
      }
  ]
}


I want to know if the problem is due to the correct format of the link in ipfs or what it could be
My Chainlink Functions subscription is 8990 on the Avalanche Fuji network
I tried to upload my own files to ipfs to test and I need to know why some .json do work and others don't, from the metadata I only need image, name and description

The IPFS link is place to save metadata that is used by front-end page to display. Whether the link format is correct or not has nothing with Chainlink Functions fulfillment since CL Functions only write the link to contract without any knowledge about content saved in IPFS link.
Since you does not show the fulfillment function, from the CL functions notifications, issue could be that callback gaslimit is set too low. One possible issue is that when your IPFS link is long, more gas limit is required, and the fulfillment might fail.
Hope it helps.

I understand that it may be with a low gas limit, but what I understood according to the documentation is that chainlink functions could only work up to 300000 gas This is a part of the contract code where I put the gas limit:

// Hardcoded for Fuji address router = 0xA9d587a00A31A52Ed70D6026794a8FC5E2F5dCb0; bytes32 donID = 0x66756e2d6176616c616e6368652d66756a692d31000000000000000000000000; uint32 gasLimit = 300000; uint64 public subscriptionId;

Can you share your fulfillRequest function? As, it might be failing due to incorrect decoding of the response or reverting due to any function that’s being called inside it.

function fulfillRequest(
        bytes32 requestId,
        bytes memory response,
        bytes memory err
    ) internal override {
        require(bytes(requestURI[requestId]).length != 0, "request not found");

        lastError = err;
        lastResponse = response;

        string memory uri = string(response);

        uint256 tokenId = _nextTokenId++;
        address owner = owner();

        _safeMint(owner, tokenId);
        _setTokenURI(tokenId, uri);

        emit Response(requestId, uri, lastResponse, lastError);
    }


This is my fulfillRequest.
